# Block content returns no results for anonymus user only

Tags: views, users

I've setup View Block that renders a custom content type. The issue is that block content shows up for logged users only. I ensured that anonymus user has "view published content" permission. No permission restrictions are set for that specific block.

any ideas what is wrong here? Could I use a Devel to inspect that somehow? thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple layers of permissions which might responsible for this,trying to cover some of them if that helps you.

- Check right in the views configuration page and check "access" should be set to "view publish content".
- Ensure you are not having contrib module like block_access or custom code which is putting a check the block view on user role basis.
- Ensure if you are using [contentaccess](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module or [nodeaccess](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module and they are not letting the block visible to anonymous user.

Comment: You are the man! Nodeaccess was overriding view permission! Thanks a bunch you saved my day! :)

Comment: @Antonio glad it helped you :)